# How to get a return an observable from AngularFirestore and resolve my router guard

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-observables, resolver, angular-router-guards

Question: How can my call to firestore and resolve my router guard with the payload returned from firestore?

Problem: My route resolve guard does not get resolved, even though the value from firestore is being returned and is defined.

```
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Resolve,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class RouteResolve implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.db
               .collection('routes')
               .doc('work')
               .valueChanges()
               .pipe(
                 map((item) => {
                   if (item) {
                     console.log('items', item) // this logs just fine.
                     return item; // this doesen't resolve the router guard.
                   }
                 }));
  }
}
```

Everything is working but the completed resolve.  If i just return true, the resolve works as intended.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  return true; // this will resolve just fine
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pipe(first())` to your `valueChanges()` observable. Angular router waits until the observable is complete, and doing this ensures that observable gets completed after the first value change.

```
return this.db
           .collection('routes')
           .doc('work')
           .valueChanges()
           .pipe(first())
           .pipe(
             map((item) => {
               if (item) {
                 console.log('items', item) // this logs just fine.
                 return item; // this doesen't resolve the router guard.
               }
             }));
```

Comment: No need. If you don't need the `console.log()`, then you can remove it.

Comment: But this does not give you real time update to the resolved data.